# Connect 4 error in logic

Tags: python, tkinter

Am trying to implement a Connect4 game in python.

For the game logic i start checking from each point in all possible directions if there are four dots in a row.
But my logic checks only until three dots in a row. Can someone please explain what i am doing wrong?

I think i am doing something wrong in recursion.

The code i have developed until now is as follows:

```
#function to ckeck if the game is over
def checkWin(row,col):
    r = row
    c = col
    #print r,c
    return checkWinFromCell(r,c)

#function to ckeck if the game is over from current cell
def checkWinFromCell(row, col):
        directions = [[0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [1,-1], [0,-1], [-1,0], [-1,-1], [-1,1]]
        for d in directions:
            canvas.data.temp = [(row,col)]
            n=1
            finalCheck(row,col,d,n)
            #print canvas.data.temp
            if (len(canvas.data.temp) == 4):
                return True

#function to ckeck if the game is over from current cell in
#all possible directions
def finalCheck(row, col, direction,n):
        drow, dcol = direction[0], direction[1]
        ddrow = row+drow #next row to check
        ddcol = col+dcol #next col to check
        #boundary checks
        if row < 0 or row>=canvas.data.rows or col < 0 or col >=canvas.data.cols:
            return False
        #boundary checks
        if ddrow < 0 or ddrow>=canvas.data.rows or ddcol < 0 or ddcol >=canvas.data.cols:
            return False
        #if same color add to list
        #print canvas.data.board[row][col]
        #print canvas.data.board[ddrow][ddcol]
        if(canvas.data.board[row][col] ==  canvas.data.board[ddrow][ddcol]):
            canvas.data.temp.append((ddrow,ddcol))
        else:
            return False
        #call 3 more times recursively to check if 4 are connected
        while(n<3):
            n += 1
            #print str(n)+" "+str(ddrow)+" "+str(ddcol)
            #print direction
            finalCheck(ddrow,ddcol,direction,n)
```

PS : I will delete the checkWin function as it does nothing.

PPS : I already tried asking this same question, but i think i was not clear in my question. I think i have tried it in a better way this time.

Comment: while n < 3 therefore 1 and 2. you want <=

Comment: this doesnt work. tried it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        while(n<3):
        n += 1
        #print str(n)+" "+str(ddrow)+" "+str(ddcol)
        #print direction
        finalCheck(ddrow,ddcol,direction,n)
```

You want n <= 3 or n < 4

Comment: I have tried it already. If i give this value, the game never ends, it keeps checking on and on.

Comment: Probably because you have an infinite loop - you're calling finalCheck from within finalCheck.

Comment: change you're while to an if. Dangerous to do recursion within a loop

Comment: yeah ! perfect guys mauve and @wckd ..!! thanks guys ! it works when i put if instead of while.. :)

Comment: Made an answer that Better described what was happening

Answer (score 1):

If you're using recursion don't use the while loop. You are likely doing 9 operations when you mean to do 3. if you unroll your code you have

```
n = 1
while n < 3
n += 1 # n is now 2
  final check
  n = 2
  while n < 3
  n += 1 # n is now 3
  final check
    n = 3
    while n < 3 #fails
  while < 3 #fails
while n < 3
n += 1 # n is now 3
  final check
  n = 3
  while n < 3 #fails
while n < 3 #fails
```

Basically change while to if

And make it n <=3 or n < 4